# MultipleHiddenInput widget doesn't get rendered

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My MultipleHiddenInput field which I am using to store some choices for another field based on a selector doesn't seem to work.

Please consider my code:

```
class LogSearch(forms.Form):
platform = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=platforms, initial='v',
                             help_text='The platform to search on')

log_type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True, choices=())

keyword = forms.CharField(required=True)

other_log_types = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput, choices=[(1, '3'), (2, 'b')])
```

As shown in this form code, I would expect the `other_log_types` to be rendered as hidden. But it doesn't appear at all in my HTML.

I am rendering it properly on the template as all other components appear properly. I'm not sure if I am not using the widget right or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by defining in the constructor the following:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fields['other_log_types'].initial = [(1, "example")]
```

I have no idea why it uses the initial and doesn't work with using choices, but ya.

Comment: If using a ManyToManyField it can render a lot of choices, and by providing the initial values you can decide how many inputs to render .